# Why Javascript isn't drawing on my canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Thanks for taking a look at my questions!

So what I'm trying to do is use a gauge chart tool made in JS ([Plugin Website](http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/)) and according to the usage section all I need to do is create a canvas element and reference the id which I did:

```
<canvas id="gauge-chart-pop" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<script src="gauge.min.js"></script> 
<script>
var opts = {
    lines: 12,
    angle: 0,
    lineWidth: 0.43,
    pointer: {
        length: 0.16,
        strokeWidth: 0.075,
        color: '#fff'
    },
    limitMax: 'false',
    colorStart: '#FFFFFF',
    colorStop: '#FFFFFF',
    strokeColor: '#F0483D',
    generateGradient: true
};

var target = document.getElementById('gauge-chart-pop');
var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts);
gauge.maxValue = 3000;
gauge.animationSpeed = 33;
gauge.set(1225);
</script>
```

All the Javascript is at the end of my document, I tried putting it at the begining but the results is always the same, the canvas just doesn't show the chart... **Please help!**

Comment: What is this bit of code at the end `});`?

Comment: What's the `});` at the end? It doesn't appear to be closing anything. Are you getting errors in the console? (hint: you should be)

Comment: @Andy Sorry, that's an error! fixed! ... still not working

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/x05g36xb/)